# How can the rng $(\mathbb{N}, +, \cdot)$ be an ideal of some ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

It is known than rng is an ideal of some ring. But how can rng $(\mathbb{N}, +, \cdot)$ be an ideal to some ring? As ring has an inverse element, the first ring we get from $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, and it seems impossible to imagine that $\mathbb{N}$ will be an ideal to $\mathbb{Z}$, for $(-3) \cdot (2) = -6$, which is not in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If you mean the natural numbers wrt the usual operation, it is far of being a ring: it isn't even an additive group!

Comment: Rng is a ring without identity. Ring without i.

Comment: $\Bbb N$ is a *semiring*, or as some people like to call rings without additive inverses, *rigs*.

Answer (score 2):

It's because $(\mathbb{N}, +, \cdot)$ is *not* a [rng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)). By definition if it were a rng, then $(\mathbb{N}, +)$ would be an abelian group, which it isn't: it does not have inverses.

However it is true that if $I \subset R$ is an ideal of a ring $R$, then $I$ is a rng (it's straightforward to check). And if $R$ is a rng, then $R_+ = R \oplus \mathbb{Z} \mathbf{1}$ is a ring (where $\mathbf{1}$ is the identity and the addition/multiplication extend that of $R$), and $R$ is an ideal of $R_+$.